# passing a variable into a function autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make a function that I can pass a variable into to print each letter of the sentence I pass it and pause for a hundredth of a second after. The problem is I am a very new programmer. Here is what I have so far:

```
testvar = this is a test

sendSentence(sentence){
    sentence = Hello world

    Loop, parse, sentence
    {
        Send %A_LoopField%
        Sleep, 10    ; replace it with "Sleep 10" in the final code.
    }
    ToolTip
    return  
}

^!i::
sendSentence(testvar)
```

I want to be able to set something to `testvar` and have it called when I run it.  I'm trying to do this with sentences.

Comment: Please indent the code.

Comment: testvar := "this is a test"



sendSentence(testvar){
 Send, %testvar%
    sentence := testvar
 
    Loop, parse, sentence
    {
        Send %A_LoopField%
        Sleep, 10    ; replace it with "Sleep 10" in the final code.
    }
    ToolTip
    return  
}

^!i::
sendSentence(testvar)


I want it to print out "this is a test"

Comment: i wanted it to print out this is a test

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having? Why are you overwriting the parameter `sentence`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
sentence = Hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is a single line you need to make it inline with your hotkey otherwise include `return` below the code.

SetKeyDelay is better than using sleep.

```
testvar = this is a test

^!i::sendSentence(testvar)

sendSentence(sentence) {
    setkeydelay, 10
    Loop, parse, sentence
        Send %A_LoopField%
    return
}
```